# Freeze after boot after recent kernel update (18.04 on Dell Inspiron 3480)

Tags: boot, 18.04, drivers, kernel, dell

I have a **Dell Inspiron 3480** that was working OK until recently. I took some days to restart it after an update (**linux-image-5.4.0-42-generic**), and since then it started freezing a few seconds after the login page is shown. I can boot in recovery mode without issues, so I am tempted to think there is something funky going on with the video drivers (**Intel® UHD Graphics 620 (WHL GT2)**). Right now I switched to **linux-image-4.15.0-1093-oem** and it works just fine, but of course I prefer to work with a newer kernel. Any help is appreciated!